# Image tags in MVC, path restrictions, base64 encoding

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

mvc app, razor .cshtml page,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

and then a couple images tags (buried in all kinds of other stuff that shouldn't matter?)

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGLk8o8pcD58AAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" /> (it's WAY longer, Visual Studio converted this one)

<img src="~/Views/Images/logosmall.png" />
```

the converted one shows, the 'regular' one doesn't in any browser, it's just an image tag, what is going on??  just thinking, is it simple a path issue?  :)

why doesn't the regular one work?

how do I convert? (I'm not sure how I converted the first one...)

is converting now best practice, what are pros/cons?

Comment: Recommend reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes, just a path issue, but still curious on conversion that I accidently stumbled upon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions one by one

**1. Why the `<img src="~/Views/Images/logosmall.png" />` doesn't work:**

ASP.NET MVC will by default put a `web.config` in your `~/Views` folder and reject any directly file access for security reason. It is not suggested to change it since all your view files will be stored in the folder in plain code. You should move your static content outside the `~/Views` folder.

**2. About the base64 img tag (your first img tag)**

Convert image into base64 string means the whole image file will be contained inline in the html, i.e. you won't need an extra http request to get the image for the html. It has pros and cons. Pros is you save 1 extra http request, cons is your html file will be heavier, and your image cannot take advantage of browser cache since it comes together with html. Use it or not is very depending on exact situation.